Endless quicksort recursive function (academic assignment)
I have a few functions here that are taking strings from an array and sorting them alphabetically. SortList is the main function, which calls functions CompareString, LastName, and FirstName. Functions LastName & FirstName simply take a string containing a full name and parse them for their respective parts. CompareString first looks at every char of two last names and compares them, returning true if the pivot value is less than the target. If the last names are the same, then it looks at both first names.
When I run it, I get the error in the attached screenshot.

public bool CompareString(string lName1, string lName2, string fName1, string fName2)
{
    // While there are letters in the last name
    for (int i = 0; i < lName1.Length && i < lName2.Length; i++)
    {
        // If letter of first string is after letter of pivot string
        if (lName1[i] > lName2[i])
            return false;
        else if (lName1[i] < lName2[i])
            return true;
        // If we get here, last names are the same
        else if (i == lName1.Length - 1 || i == lName2.Length - 1)
        {

            // While there are letters in the first name
            for (int j = 0; j < fName1.Length && j < fName2.Length; j++)
            {
                // If letter of first string is less than letter of pivot string
                if (fName1[j] < fName2[j])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        } // End first name compare

    } // End name compare

    // Pivot string is first alphabetically
    return true;

} // End CompareString


// PURPOSE: Fills array with data from file
// PRE:
// POST: Array filled with data from file
public void SortList(int leftInd, int rightInd)
{
    int l = leftInd;    // initialized with 0 
    int r = rightInd;   // initialized with numDivers - 1

   // DiverRec pivot = diverList[leftInd];       // set to first value
    DiverRec temp;

    // Assign last names to left, right, & pivot
    string lLast = LastName(diverList[l].name);
    string rLast = LastName(diverList[r].name);
    string pLast = LastName(diverList[l].name);

    // Assign first names to left, right, & pivot
    string lFirst = FirstName(diverList[l].name);
    string rFirst = FirstName(diverList[r].name);
    string pFirst = FirstName(diverList[l].name);


    // Compare left & right strings with pivot
    while (l <= r)
    {
        while (CompareString(lLast, pLast, lFirst, pFirst))
        {
            l++;
            lLast = LastName(diverList[l].name);
            lFirst = FirstName(diverList[l].name);
        }

        while (!CompareString(rLast, pLast, rFirst, pFirst))
        {
            r--;
            rLast = LastName(diverList[r].name);
            rFirst = FirstName(diverList[r].name);
        }


        if (l <= r)
        {
            temp = diverList[l];
            diverList[l] = diverList[r];
            diverList[r] = temp;

            l++;
            r--;
        }

    }
   
    if (leftInd < r)
        SortList(leftInd, r);
    if (l < rightInd)
        SortList(l, rightInd);

    /*if (l > r)
    {
        temp = diverList[r];
        diverList[r] = pivot;
        pivot = temp;

        l++;
        r--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numDivers - 1; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(diverList[i].name);*/



} // End SortList


public string LastName(string lName)
{
    char delim = ' ';                   // Separates first & last name
    int pos = lName.IndexOf(delim);     // Position of delim

    // Isolate last name
    string last = lName.Substring(pos + 1, lName.Length - (pos + 1));

    // Return last name
    return last;

} // End LastName
public string FirstName(string fName)
{
    char delim = ' ';                   // Separates first & last name
    int pos = fName.IndexOf(delim);     // Position of delim

    // Isolate first name
    string first = fName.Substring(0, pos);

    // Return first name
    return first;

} // End FirstName

I've tried multiple things, making sure I'm incrementing & decrementing in the right places, making sure the strings are read in correctly... I'm almost certain that the issue is somewhere in the recursive function because I only learned about it last week so I'm not really confident in implementing it yet. Thank you in advance to anyone who's willing to lend a hand.

Any reason for tackling this recursively? -> "The exception that is thrown when the execution stack exceeds the stack size." - you ran into the one problem, recursive attempts are notorious for. You ran out of memory.

Since QuickSort is inherently recursive, I would chose a different one. If this is rather academic, then you'll probably need to 1. accept less input and 2. heavily optimize your string-related stuff.

Can you explain to us why you are building your own sort rather than using a built-in one?

There is also an iterative variant of quicksort if you are allowed / willing to consider that, then you will probably be able to avoid the SOE.

@Fildor Okay, thank you for your input. I'll try to tackle it with a different sort.

BTW, if this is part of an academic assignment, then it is strongly recommended to state that in the question.

@mjwills Unfortunately because my professor said so...

What specifically did your professor ask for? Did they ask for it to be recursive?

@Fildor Thank you, I'll edit this one and make sure to include that in the future.

@Antonio1113 Be aware that it may well be that your professor wanted you to run into this problem. So, I would mention this failed attempt, what the problem was and why it made you take the decisions that followed.

@mjwills No, just that "Sorts must be coded, do not use the static Array.Sort() function"

The cheeky part of me would suggest you sort it using OrderBy, which technically isn't using Array.Sort.

^^ lol. "There, I fixed it" ... haha. Well, I guess the assignment is to explore sorting algorithms. Chosing Quicksort for learning purposes isn't too bad, neither. It is quite simple and quickly shows where the problems arise. If your professor only gave you an input set and "no built-in sorting", I'd probably go for the iterative variant and try to be smart about the string-related stuff. Maybe also explore some others to compare performance (theoretical and practical). If you are able to factor out a comparer on the input items, algos should be easily replacable.

Your comparison function is not consistent. If both the first and last name of the first person are prefixes of the first and last name of the second person, the call to CompareString will return True, no matter if you swap the person's names.

The loop conditions are not correct. When l and r are equal, then the inner loop will access diverList[r+1] which is outside the current partition, and which might even be outside of the array.

Was it also part of the requirements to manually compare every letter in your CompareString() function? That could have been written in four lines or less...
